# Program finishes if user does not select yes/no to continue - java

Tags: java

I am having a little bit of a logic issue which I need a little guidance for. Basically I am asking the user if they want to play again. If they select yes then they play again and this works fine. If they select no then it gives a thank you message and the game is finished (console stops). This also works fine.

My problem is when the user does not enter either yes or no. If they enter in something else then the correct message is displayed where it asks the user again if they want to play or not yes or no, however the game then ends.

I can see the problem is that the while loop only works if `weArePlaying` is 1. But as it equals 2, it will come out of the loop and so the game ends.

So my question is how can I overcome this problem?

Below is the basic structure of my code where you can see what happens if `we are playing equals 1, 2 or 0`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\mmkp1\\Documents\\listofmovies.txt");
    int attempts = 10;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int weArePlaying = 1;

    while (weArePlaying == 1)
    {

         ...

        // This is in the while loop and I think this is why it end abruptly
        // as the value for areWePlaying does not equal 1 if we don't select
        // 1 or 2

        if (weArePlaying == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)");
            String anotherGame = scanner.nextLine();
            if (anotherGame.equals("no"))
            {
                weArePlaying = 0;
            } else if (anotherGame.equals("yes"))
            {
                weArePlaying = 1;
                attempts = 10;
                guessedLetters.clear();
            } else
            {
                weArePlaying = 2;
                System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)");
            }
        }
    }

    if (weArePlaying == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing :)");
    }

}
```

Comment: Try changing `if (weArePlaying == 2)` to `while(weArePlaying == 2)`

Comment: Omg so obvious when someone points it out. Thanks

Comment: however your outer most loop won't terminate when weArePlaying == 0... you should palce a break inside your last if(weArePlaying == 0)

Comment: Also use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` to compare the input to "yes" and "no" so that it won't matter whether they capitalize the first letter of the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the else condtion block as mentioned. Making `weArePlaying` to `1` will cause it again to enter while loop.

```
if (anotherGame.equals("no")) {
    weArePlaying = 0;
} else if (anotherGame.equals("yes")) {
    weArePlaying = 1;
    attempts = 10;
    guessedLetters.clear();
}
else {
    weArePlaying = 1;
}
```